# Load txt file into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying fill in a database from a file but I am getting the following error : Could not load. Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
I am using a free webhosting service. How do I resolve this?

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
$string = file_get_contents("testdata.txt"); 
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$fileContents = file_get_contents('testdata.txt');
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE table1;'); //clear the existing table
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'myFile.txt'" .
                      " INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'");
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}
echo 'OK8';
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1"; 
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'Query success.';
    if (mysql_num_rows($query_run)==NULL){
        echo 'No results found.';
    } else {
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        echo json_encode($query_row);
    }
    }
}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: *Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)* appears when you're unable to connect to database engine.

Comment: This is my code in connect.inc.php, and it is index.php outputs connected before displaying the above mentioned error.
    if(!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)||!@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
     die($conn_error);
    } else {
     echo 'Connected.';
    }

Comment: It might be than you have to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Yes, stupid and annoying, but this can be depending on how your hosting provider setup the deamon.

Comment: I tried using 127.0.0.1, but it is still displaying  Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'.  the following line of code is posing a problem. It doesn't executes and dies.
    
    $result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'myFile.txt'" ." INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'");

Answer (score 0):

The access denied error for user 'user'@'localhost' could mean that:

1. the 'user'@'localhost' doesn't have the FILE privilege. you should grant this privilege. Or you should check that the configuration you are using is ok (user exists and has all the necessary privileges on the corresponding database)
2. the file you are trying to load does not exist **on the machine running mysql server**

If you want to load the file from your machine you should use
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE instead.

3. Check that the file you are trying to load is readable try chmod 755 for the file and for all the parent directories of 'myFile.txt')

Comment: Try to remove this part, just for test.To check that evrything else is ok:$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'myFile.txt'" .
                      " INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'");
if (!$result) {
    die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}

Comment: When the following code is removed, it shows query success. No results found. This means the database is able to connect. The file exists and I have given it 777 permission.